# How to set permissions for a program and not the user

Tags: php, linux, command-line, permissions, apache2

I have a Linux based system running a webserver (apache2).
Via this webserver it should be possible to set/change the IP address in the file "etc/network/interfaces" and store the corresponding settings in a file on the SD card. These changes should be able to make by executing a command.
At the moment it does not work because "www-data" does not have the rights to change the files.

I can change owner and permissions for the files, but I have two problems with that:

- The user "www-data" of the webserver should not have access to the files and only execute the changes by the corresponding command.
- After each removal and reinsertion of the SD card, the "owner" is reset.

Maybe someone can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the file's permission to be only executable and only for a certain user using `setfacl` - this would also set the file's permission to what you need even after recreating the file.

Read more here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl